# How to convert a String to PFObject

Tags: ios, string, swift, parse-platform, pfobject

I've saved userIds in a column in parse as `String` and i want to convert it in `PFObject` . How can i do it in swift?  I was trying to retrieve the userIds as follows:

```
followedUserQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

            if let objects = objects {

                for object in objects {

                    var followedUser = object["user"] as! PFObject
```

and i am getting this error:

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x105f94c50) to 'PFObject' (0x104708998).
```

thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't believe you can simply cast a String to PFObject. PFObjects can have String properties but they cannot be Strings themselves.

Comment: this is what i think too. But that would make me code again "a lot" if i'll have to change the properties in PFObject which are saved as String. So, i thought it would be better to convert it . :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
followedUserQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject], error:NSError) -> Void in
          if error == nil{
     if let objects = objects as! [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
             var followedUser = object["user"] 
            }
}
```

Comment: It's giving a warning `var 'followedUser' inferred to have type 'AnyObject?', which maybe unexpected`

Comment: Just do some like var followUser: AnyObject = object["user"] and try to run the code

Comment: warning is not there but it's not converting it in a `Pointer` , so getting no data to display.

Comment: Try to change it to var followUser= object["user"] as! String

Comment: but i want it as Pointer not String

Comment: i am querying the followedUser in a class where `user` has userIds as String then i am comparing it in other class called `Posts` to a column `postedBy` which has pointers of userIds. so by using `object["user"] as! String ` i get this error : `pointer field postedBy needs a pointer value (Code: 102, Version: 1.7.4)`

Comment: But why don't you downcast those value as String then it would be easier to compare them